# How to avoid repetition of columns of same type in database

Tags: mysql, database

I am building a database that will save entities such as: orders, cart, customers etc.

All these tables share some common attributes such as: a date, the user agent that was used to create the new element and the ip address of the client.

Would it be considered "ok" to create a separate table that will store these common attributes:

```
log_id | log_date_added | user_agent_id | ipaddress
```

Then the field `log_id` would be added in the tables orders, carts, customers etc.

My first worry is that I will have to make a JOIN operation on the log table to get the date of any order creation, cart creation, or customer creation.

My second worry is that the more the log table gets bigger, the more it will impact on performances when retrieving the date, user agent, ipaddress for any entity that requires it.

In the same time, I feel it would be very redundant to add the fields `date_added`, `user_agent_id`, `ip_address` in all the tables that need those information.

Any best practice recomendation on that matter is more than welcome, thank you

Comment: your question might be better fit on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: May i ask why you are storing `user_agent_id` an `ip_adress`

Are you trying to log the actions of the users? if so `ip_adress` is not really useful because many users will have an IP address that will vary (a lot of providers don't provide a static IP address to their users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say both options are possible but my personal preference would go to just saving it inside the table.

It's not really redundant because the information your storing is different data, it just happens to have the same form and be somewhat similar.

The general rule is, if the relation between a table is a one to one (which it is in this case) you should save it in one table, instead of splitting it up in two.

To summarize:

- Splitting it might cause slower queries
- It's harder for someone new to understand the database
- No real upside from it in this case (as far as i can see)

P.S. you can use a TimeStamp column and let the database enter a TimeStamp automatically on create